# will CompletableFuture callback always be executed

Tags: java, completable-future

I have two service calls:

```
String call1() { ... return "ok"; }
void call2(String) { ... }
```

I know the basic way for CompletableFuture with callback is like

```
CompletableFuture<Void> future = CompletableFuture
.supplyAsync(() -> call1())
.thenAccept(s -> call2(s));
future.join();
```

What if I separate the two chained CompletableFutures, like:

```
CompletableFuture<String> future1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> call1());
CompletableFuture<Void> future2 = future1.thenAccept(s -> call2(s));
future1.join(); // will call2 be executed at this time?
```

Is this any different from calling join() on future2:

```
CompletableFuture<String> future1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> call1());
CompletableFuture<Void> future2 = future1.thenAccept(s -> call2(s));
future2.join();
```

What if I call join() on both of the futures?

```
CompletableFuture<String> future1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> call1());
CompletableFuture<Void> future2 = future1.thenAccept(s -> call2(s));
future1.join();
future2.join();
```

It seems they are all the same from running my sample code. But I feel something might be wrong somewhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

They are not the same.

In short, you can look at it as `future1` and `future2` hold results of distinct tasks (even if `future2` uses the result of `future1`, it's a different future).

`future1.join()` will block until `() -> call1()` ends, and `future2`'s task won't start until then. `future2.join()` will wait until `s -> call2(s)` is done.

> What if I separate the two chained CompletableFutures, like:

This makes no difference as far as task execution is concerned. It's either a question of style or it only matters when you need to use the two future objects separately.

> What if I call join() on both of the futures?

It's redundant in this case to call `future1.join()` as you are not doing anything between the two `.join` calls. It would make sense if you wanted to perform some action "after completion of task1 and before the completion of task 2".

In this case, though, calling `future2.join()` is enough.

---

And the code snippet below should show how this behaves:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CompletableFuture<Void> future1 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> delay());
    CompletableFuture<Void> future2 = future1.thenRun(() -> delay());

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    future1.join();
    System.out.println("Future 1 done. Waiting for future 2: " 
            + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));

    future2.join();
    System.out.println("Future 2 complete: " 
            + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
}

static void delay() {
    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

As it is, this code outputs:

```
Future 1 done. Waiting for future 2: 5001
Future 2 complete: 10001
```

But when you remove `future1.join()`, the output becomes:

```
Future 2 complete: 10001
```

Which simply means that `future1.join()` is superfluous unless you have actions to perform between the completions of the two futures

Comment: Thanks. Are all those still valid if the second future is async? i.e. CompletableFuture<Void> future2 = future1.thenRunAsync(() -> delay()); in your code? Then I think calling future2.join() will be blocking on main thread, and lose the intention of calling future2 on async? But can calling future1.join() guarantee future2 will be executed?

Answer (score 2):

The `supplyAsync` and `thenAccept` methods should be executed on a separate thread automatically according to the documentation:

> All async methods without an explicit Executor argument are performed using the ForkJoinPool.commonPool()

In your examples, the only difference is your thread waits on different events before continuing due to the joining.  Here is the breakdown:

```
CompletableFuture<Void> future = CompletableFuture
.supplyAsync(() -> call1())
.thenAccept(s -> call2(s));
future.join();
```

This will wait until `call2` completes because that is the future returned by `thenAccept` method.

```
CompletableFuture<String> future1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> call1());
CompletableFuture<Void> future2 = future1.thenAccept(s -> call2(s));
future1.join(); // will call2 be executed at this time?
```

This will only wait until `call1` completes and moves on.  `call2` will still gets executed.

```
CompletableFuture<String> future1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> call1());
CompletableFuture<Void> future2 = future1.thenAccept(s -> call2(s));
future2.join();
```

This is identical to the first one.

```
CompletableFuture<String> future1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> call1());
CompletableFuture<Void> future2 = future1.thenAccept(s -> call2(s));
future1.join();
future2.join();
```

Calling `future1.join()` ends when `call1` completed, then `future2.join()` ends when `call2` completed.  This should be identical functionally with the first one as well.

Comment: Thanks. Then what if the thenAccept() is changed to thenAcceptAsync()? I guess this will just put call2() on a third thread, but all the other arguments are still valid?

Comment: Yes, that's right, but normally you want to call `thenAcceptAsync()` if you need to do multiple tasks in parallel.